# Apending session values to existing array structure for API request php

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am using an API where each request to the API should resend all the previous values. I am storing all the previous values in a php session.The resulting array structure is to be json_encoded and used for Curl request. Everything is working fine except appending new questions to existing one. The following is the code:

```
$question_counter = ++$_SESSION['question_counter'];
$questionidnew = strip_tags($_POST['questionid1']);
$answernew = strip_tags($_POST['answer1']);
//store new questions as session array
$_SESSION['questions'][$question_counter] = array(
    'questionid' => $questionidnew,
    'questionanswer' => $answernew,
    );
$question_array[] = $_SESSION['questions'];//previous questions
```

`print_r($question_array);` gives following results:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
[1] => Array ( [questionid] => p_48 [questionanswer] => absent ) 
[2] => Array ( [questionid] => p_122 [questionanswer] => absent ) 
) )
```

**How can i append it to existing data structure in format:**

```
$to_json = [
  'sex' => $gender,
  'age' => $age,
  'evidence' => [
    ['id' => $test_id1, 'choice_id' => 'present', 'initial' => true],
    ['id' => $test_id2, 'choice_id' => 'present', 'initial' => true],
    ['id' => $questionidnew, 'choice_id' => $answernew],
    ['id' => 'p_12', 'choice_id' => $choice, 'initial' => true],
    ['id' => $location, 'choice_id' => 'present', 'initial' => true]
  ],
  'extras' => [
    'disable_users' => true
  ],
];
```

Since i am a newbie programmer, i am getting errors and find it bit confusing to add the following for previous questions from session:

```
['id' => $questionidnew, 'choice_id' => $answernew],
```

Requesting help.

Comment: I tried array_push($question_array,$to_json = [
The first question and answer gets overwritten..

Comment: Also tried: foreach($question_array as $key => $value)
{
$to_json['evidence'][] = ['id' => $key, 'choice_id' => $value];
}

Comment: No solutions ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading this correctly, you want to add all new answers to the $to_json array, right? I ended up doing the following to accomplish that. I took liberties and may have misunderstood, so please correct me if this is not helpful:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['question_counter'])) {
  $_SESSION['question_counter'] = 0;
}

$gender = "male";
$age = 46;
$test_id1 = 12;
$test_id2 = 24;
$questionidnew = 9;
$answernew = "B";
$choice = "A";
$location = "campus";

$to_json = array(
  'sex' => $gender,
  'age' => $age,
  'evidence' => array(
    array('id' => $test_id1, 'choice_id' => 'present', 'initial' => true),
    array('id' => $test_id2, 'choice_id' => 'present', 'initial' => true),
    array('id' => $questionidnew, 'choice_id' => $answernew),
    array('id' => 'p_12', 'choice_id' => $choice, 'initial' => true),
    array('id' => $location, 'choice_id' => 'present', 'initial' => true)
  ),
  'extras' => array(
    'disable_users' => true
  ),
);

$question_counter = ++$_SESSION['question_counter'];
//$questionidnew = strip_tags($_POST['questionid1']);
//$answernew = strip_tags($_POST['answer1']);
//store new questions as session array
$_SESSION['questions'][$question_counter] = array(
    'questionid' => $questionidnew,
    'questionanswer' => $answernew,
    );
$question_array[] = $_SESSION['questions'];//previous questions

echo "<pre>";
print_r($to_json);
echo "</pre>";
//$_SESSION['names'][] = $name;

foreach($question_array as $question) {
  foreach($question as $key => $value) {
    $to_json['evidence'][] = array('id' => $value['questionid'], 'choice_id' => $value['questionanswer']);
  }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($to_json);
echo "</pre>";
print_r(json_encode($to_json));
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much dear. You saved my day. Everything was perfect except that i was storing new questions as session array before $to_json = array( .. rather than after it. Thanking you once again for taking so much pain to help me.

Comment: Wonderful, I am glad to hear you have figured it out!